# Определение наличия зависимости величины функции от аргумента

Tags: анализ-данных, численные-методы, корреляционный-анализ

Пусть задана фмп F(x1,x2 ... xn) в пространстве R^n заданная точками, известно, что значение функции зависит только от некоторых аргументов xi, как численно определить что F зависит только от x1,x2,x4 например, а остальные аргументы роли не играют??

Я решил изначально проверить наличие зависимости значения F от каждого из аргументов в отдельности.

Я пробовал КК Пирсона в прявязке со шкалой Чеддока, но я как понял он хорошо может работать только если точки нормально распределены(так ли это?), тогда начал смотреть Кенделла и Спирмена, но любые выбросы очень сильно влияют на результат.

Какие есть общепринятые практики и методы решения этой задачи?
Более того, хотелось бы как-то ловить ситуации ложной корреляции (из разряда "чем короче шорты мы носим летом, тем теплее на улице")

Comment: Из общих соображений, нужно проверить `n` статистических гипотез *частная производная `dF/dx_i` равна нулю* В качестве случайной величины можно взять квадрат частной производной и проверить, математической ожидание этой величины равно нулю в N случайно выбранных точках в пространстве.

Comment: Кстати, ваш пример с шортами - это НЕ ложная корреляция.  Это -  упускание из виду, что коэф. корреляции показывает наличие/отсутствие связи, но ничего не говорит о том, какой параметр от какого зависит. И так бывает всегда. Ложная корреляция  - это зависимость урожая риса в префектуре Акита в Японии от количества фильмов, в которых снялся Николас Кейдж. Как говориться -  почувствуйте разницу.